# Sorting list items based on postion on canvas in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, sorting, canvas

I am drawing rectangles on a html5 canvas with the below json format using angularjs and javascript. 
I need to sort the array based on the x,y location.

```
{
"obj0": {
"outerRects": [
  {
    "outerRectRoi": {
      "x1": 0,
      "x2": 650,
      "x3": 350,
      "x4": 340,
      "y1": 0,
      "y2": 680,
      "y3": 0,
      "y4": 680
    },
    "line": [
      {
        "lineRoi": {
          "x1": 471,
          "x2": 460,
          "y1": 1,
          "y2": 680
        },
        "innerRect": [
          {
            "innerRoi": {
              "x1": 368,
              "x2": 390,
              "y1": 50,
              "y2": 55
            }
          },
          {
            "innerRoi": {
              "x1": 368,
              "x2": 390,
              "y1": 70,
              "y2": 74
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "lineRoi": {
          "x1": 202,
          "x2": 197,
          "y1": 1,
          "y2": 680
        }
      },
      {
        "lineRoi": {
          "x1": 380,
          "x2": 372,
          "y1": 1,
          "y2": 680
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {}
]
},
"obj1": {}
}
```

These are the conditions to be sorted based on the Roi or position on the canvas:

a. The outer rectangles (outerRects) have to be sorted from left to right. They can be in multiple rows as below

```
1  2

3  4
```

b. The lines are also to be sorted from left to right within the outer rect.

c. The innerRects are to be sorted from top to bottom based on their postition on top of the lines.

This would be the expected json result

```
{
"obj0": {
"outerRects": [
  {
    "outerRectRoi": {
      "x1": 0,
      "x2": 650,
      "x3": 350,
      "x4": 340,
      "y1": 0,
      "y2": 680,
      "y3": 0,
      "y4": 680
    },
    "line": [
      {
        "lineRoi": {
          "x1": 202,
          "x2": 197,
          "y1": 1,
          "y2": 680
        },
        "innerRect": []
      },
      {
        "lineRoi": {
          "x1": 380,
          "x2": 372,
          "y1": 1,
          "y2": 680
        },
        "innerRext": []
      },
      {
        "lineRoi": {
          "x1": 471,
          "x2": 460,
          "y1": 1,
          "y2": 680
        },
        "innerRect": [
          {
            "innerRoi": {
              "x1": 368,
              "x2": 390,
              "y1": 70,
              "y2": 74
            }
          },
          {
            "innerRoi": {
              "x1": 368,
              "x2": 390,
              "y1": 50,
              "y2": 55
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {}
]
},
"obj1": {}
}
```

How can i do this using angularjs and javascript?

Thanks

Comment: please add the wanted result. and add the reference points.

Comment: Could you please check my edit in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the various arrays and sort the sub array with their properties according to you needs.

```js
var object = { "obj0": { "outerRects": [{ "outerRectRoi": { "x1": 0, "x2": 650, "x3": 350, "x4": 340, "y1": 0, "y2": 680, "y3": 0, "y4": 680 }, "line": [{ "lineRoi": { "x1": 471, "x2": 460, "y1": 1, "y2": 680 }, "innerRect": [{ "innerRoi": { "x1": 368, "x2": 390, "y1": 50, "y2": 55 } }, { "innerRoi": { "x1": 368, "x2": 390, "y1": 70, "y2": 74 } }] }, { "lineRoi": { "x1": 202, "x2": 197, "y1": 1, "y2": 680 } }, { "lineRoi": { "x1": 380, "x2": 372, "y1": 1, "y2": 680 } }] }, {}] }, "obj1": {} }

object.obj0.outerRects.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.line) {
        a.line.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.lineRoi.x1 - b.lineRoi.x1;
        });
        a.line.forEach(function (b) {
            if (b.innerRect) {
                b.innerRect.sort(function (a, b) {
                    return a.innerRoi.y1 - b.innerRoi.y1;
                });
            }
        });
    }
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks .This was very useful. I have one query though. The outerRects will also be a list of items which have to be sorted based on their position(x,y). And also randomly drawn. So how can i sort them from left to right?

Comment: And my bad. But the inner rects wil have to be sorted such that the point y with higher value(since it has to be plotted from top to bottom) has to be the first in the list. I have edited the question. :)

Comment: you can change the return values, if the sort order is reverse `return a.lineRoi.x1 - b.lineRoi.x1;`. the object `obj0` and `obj1` can not be sorted, because objects have no order, or do you mean the items inside `outerRec`?

Comment: Yes. If you notice outerRects is an array of objects which have the property outerRectRoi i.e is the x,y coordinates on the canvas. I need them to be sorted too from left to the right of the canvas.